# Adding mathematica plot symbols to latex figure legend

Tags: latex, wolfram-mathematica

I have a graph that I have drawn in Mathematica using this code:

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Large}, PlotTheme -> "Default"]
```

I have exported the figure and I want to add the symbols from the plot to my figure legend in LaTeX. I know that latex already has `\blacksquare` which is the equivalent of `\[FilledSquare]` in Mathematica but I want all of the shapes in the exact colors of those from the graph

Answer (score 1):

Specify the colours and sizes with `Style`.

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}},
 PlotMarkers -> {
   Style["\[FilledSquare]", Red, 20],
   Style["\[FilledSquare]", Blue, 20],
   Style["\[FilledSquare]", Green, 20]},
 PlotTheme -> "Default"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to extract the markers to use as separate graphics?  Try this:

```
ListPlot[...]//Fullform
```

you will get a bunch of code with things like:

```
Directive[RGBColor[0.2472, 0.24, 0.6]], Inset[
   Style["\[FilledCircle]", Rule[FontSize, Large]], 10],
```

which represent individual markers.

After a bit of manipulation you can export them like this:

```
Export["test.eps",  (* or tiff or whatever.. *)
    Style["\[FilledCircle]", RGBColor[0.2472, 0.24, 0.6],
         Rule[FontSize, Large]]]
```

Ultimately these things are font glyphs so you might also be able to directly use the mathematica font within latex.

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I wanted to do!! Thank you!!